# ЗАМЕНА пробелов в файлах и папках стандартными средствами bash

Tags: bash, for, termux

используется андройд устройство с termux. Такая ситуация, папки и файлы должны быть в оригинальном виде, а на конвертацию надо отправлять.

Самый эффективный алгоритм получается такой:

1.заменить пробелы на спецсимволы
2.выполнить конвертацию
3.заменить спецсимволы обратно на пробелы

в случаях с файлами

замена:
`find "/storage/emulated/0/Notifications" -type f -name "* *" -exec bash -c 'mv "$0" "${0// /♡}"' {} \;`

обратная замена:
`find "/storage/emulated/0/Notifications" -type f -name "*♡*" -exec bash -c 'mv "$0" "${0//♡/ }"' {} \;`

работает, пока папка с пробелами не попадётся.

Найден также такой вариант замены пробелов и в папках и в файлах:

`cd "/storage/emulated/0/Notifications"`
`for x in *" "*; do mv -- "$x" "${x// /♡}" done`
но он отрабатывает только файлы и папки в текущей папке, то есть если в папке /storage/emulated/0/Notifications есть подпапка "поющие трусы" то она переименуется, а вот все файлы и папки которые внутри папки "поющие трусы" уже не переименовываются.

То есть глубина вложения равна единице, а надо минимум пятёрку, а лучше без ограничений

Comment: Делайте за 2 прохода, 1-й проход переименовать папки, заменить пробел на "_", 2-й переименовать файлы.

Comment: так глубина вложений для папок недостаточна, там дофига проходов получится, я не против за первый проход переименовать файлы, а за второй папки - с папками проблема.

Comment: кажется нужно отказатся от финда и сделать вложенный цикл.    
    For
    (перебор папок внутри /storage/emulated/0/Notifications)
    do
    for x in *" "*; do mv -- "$x" "${x// /♡}"
    done
    done

Answer (score 1):

Рассмотрите использование цикла вместо `exec`

```
while read file; do
#Получаем имя файла из пути
    FileName="${file##*/}"
#Подставляем каталог, убираем в файле пробелы заносим в переменную
    NoSpace="${file%/*}/${FileName// /♡}"
#Переименовываем
    mv "$file" "$NoSpace"
#Тут комманду конвертации или чего-то еще требующего отсутствия пробелов
    ... $NoSpcace
#Возвращаем имя
    mv "$NoSpace" "$file"
done< <(find "/storage/emulated/0/Notifications" -type f -name "* *")
```